# Get the center point of a custom overlay

Tags: android, overlay

So I have an custom overlay item that I have written to fill in a transparent blue overlay based around an array of geo points

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

    Paint fill = new Paint();
    fill.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    fill.setAlpha(50);
    fill.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

    Path path = new Path();
    Point firstPoint = new Point();
    projection.toPixels(geoPoints.get(0), firstPoint);
    path.moveTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);

    for (int i = 1; i < geoPoints.size(); ++i) {
        Point nextPoint = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(geoPoints.get(i), nextPoint);
        path.lineTo(nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
    }

    path.lineTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
    path.setLastPoint(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);

    canvas.drawPath(path, fill);

    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
}
```

What I need is a way to get the center point of this overlay so I can place a marker on it,
anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although i am not familiar with android framework, i assume you writing in java and using some kind of google maps api. But i do familiar with graphics and geo development. My suggestion to you firsst of all to check whether the standard api has some kind of 
getBounds(path) that returns to you RectangularBounds object or similar. Then from rectangular bounds you can ask for bounds.getCenter() which returns the center of bounds as geo point or other metric. If you use pixels just convert the geopoint like you did...

If getBounds doesn't exists in api (what is hard to believe), just implement a simple interface , you can find a lot of examples on the net.

simple pseudo code for finding the bounds of a geo shape for geo points, if you need pixels use x,y respectively:

```
bounds = { topLeft: new GeoPoint(path[0]), bottomRight: new GeoPoint(path[0])};
for( point in path ){
    bounds.topLeft.lat = max( bounds.topLeft.lat,point.lat );
    bounds.topLeft.lng = min( bounds.topLeft.lng,point.lng );
    bounds.bottomRight.lat = min( bounds.bottomRight.lat,point.lat );
    bounds.bottomRight.lng = max( bounds.bottomRight.lng,point.lng );
}

bounds.getCenter(){
    return new GeoPoint(rectangle center point); 
    // i am sure you will able to manage the code here )))
}
```

hope this will help

Comment: you were right I was overlooking a method already in the API for centerX and centerY, thanks